# Can I access, download, and upload files to AWS EFS via the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs, aws-sdk-net

I just want to access, download, and upload files on AWS EFS.

What packages need to be installed or what is the code for it if I'm using .NET?

Comment: What do you mean by "through an API"?

Comment: Ignore the API aspects; I just want to access, download, and upload files on AWS EFS. What packages need to be installed or what is the code for it if i am using .Net?

Comment: From what I can tell, you can't use EFS like S3; EFS is designed to be mounted as a filesystem - I can't see any sign of a HTTP interface into an EFS filesystem instance. You'd have to create your own that runs in an EC2 instance such that the EC2 instance as the EFS mounted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll explore the AWSSDK.ElasticFileSystem package and see if it fits our requirements for accessing, downloading, and uploading files on AWS EFS. I appreciate your guidance and "If you have any insights or tips regarding the usage of AWSSDK.ElasticFileSystem for accessing files from EFS, feel free to share. Your expertise would be valuable as I explore and implement this solution.

Comment: The `AWSSDK.ElasticFileSystem` library is for management/administration tasks _only_, like creating filesystems, setting AWS tags, and configuring replication - it doesn't contain any functionality for working with the contents of the filesystem instance.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EFS is an elastic NFS file system i.e. network drive as a service.

The file system needs to be [mounted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html) on e.g. EC2 instances, a Lambda function, ECS, EKS or locally before you can access it via the [NFSv4 protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

You can't just upload files to it via any of the AWS SDKs, including the AWS SDK for .NET. The [`AWSSDK.ElasticFileSystem`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.ElasticFileSystem) is a control-plane package for accessing the EFS service, not for interacting with the EFS drives themselves.

Comment: I believe we can utilize the file system to upload and read files from AWS EFS

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can utilize the file system (System.IO) to upload and read files from AWS EFS in Net.